# Can concurrency, in a server, be implemented using only a single thread?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, concurrent-programming, single-threaded

I know multithreading is ideal for this situation, but would there be any instance of where this situation could be applicable?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "concurrency" in this context.

Comment: Concurrency on a server application.  Ideally a server would wait for a client request and create a child thread for that request, but would there be a case to where a single thread listen be useful? (sorry I'm not sure if I worded that right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could be serving multiple clients at once from a single thread. This is typically implemented using the select() or poll() socket functions.

A single threaded select() based polling server can use less system resources than a multi-threaded server.